# T-SQL. Как связать две таблицы, если нет прямой взаимосвязи

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы Таб1 и Таб2.
Таб1 содержит перечень номеров, к примеру таких:

```
100
101
102
...
110
```

Таб 2 содержит перечень категорий(столбец 1) и числовых соответствий (столбец 2), к примеру так:

```
| Кат1 |  3  |
| Кат2 |  2  |
| Кат3 |  5  |
| Кат4 |  1  |
```

Необходимо получить результирующую таблицу Таб3, которая будет содержать перечень номеров из Таб1 и перечень соответствий категорий из Таб2. Индекс из колонки 1 означает то, сколько номеров из Таб1 принадлежат указанной категории
Результирующая таблица должна выглядеть так:

```
| 100 |  Кат1  |
| 101 |  Кат1  |
| 102 |  Кат1  |
| 103 |  Кат2  |
| 104 |  Кат2  |
| 105 |  Кат3  |
| 106 |  Кат3  |
| 107 |  Кат3  |
| 108 |  Кат3  |
| 109 |  Кат3  |
| 110 |  Кат4  |
```

Собственно, проблема в том, что не понимаю, по какому принципу можно связать Таб1 и Таб2, чтобы получить результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения задачи вам понадобится посчитать порядковый номер каждой строки из таблицы Таб1, и также посчитать нарастающим итогом во второй таблице, какие именно строки надо присоединять.

```
with [Таб1] as 
(
    select tab.Id
    from (values (100), (101), (102), (103), (104), 
                 (105), (106), (107), (108), (109), (110)) as tab (Id)
), [Таб2] as 
(
    select tab.Name, tab.Cnt
    from (values ('Кат1', 3), ('Кат2', 2), ('Кат3', 5), ('Кат4', 1)) as tab (Name, Cnt)
)
select  tab1.Id, tab2.Name
from   (select  name
            ,   sum(Cnt) over (order by name) + 1 - Cnt as Cnt_From
            ,   sum(Cnt) over (order by name) as Cnt_To 
        from    [Таб2]) as tab2
        inner join (select  id, row_number() over (order by Id) as rn 
                    from    [Таб1]) as tab1 
                on tab1.rn between tab2.Cnt_From and tab2.Cnt_To
```

Comment: Благодарю. То, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить в Таб1 поле, такое же как вторая колонка в Таб3. И будут это сторонние ключи из Таб2. Так Вы свяжете Таб1 и Таб2

Comment: Оно то да, но сейчас я это могу вручную только добавить. Для кол-ва номеров из примера - это ок, но если значений в Таб 1 несколько тысяч, то уже сложнее.